# Using sed to output a file from first line and up to but not including a regular expression match

Tags: regex, file, sed

I'd like to use sed to collect the top section from a set of files and output the collected result to a digest file. What I am currently doing almost works:

`for i in foo/*/bazz.txt; do sed '/regexp/ q' $i >> bazzdigest.txt; done`

The problem is that the line that matches /regexp/ also gets included. I don't want to include it, so I have an extra-step of going into the file and removing it afterwards. Is there a way to do this so that that line does not get included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk solution:

```
for i in foo/*/bazz.txt; do awk '/regexp/ {exit} {print}' "$i" >> bazzdigest.txt; done
```

Comment: Thank you -- I like this solution the best. It's very clear what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for i in foo/*/bazz.txt; do sed '/regexp/,$ d' $i >> bazzdigest.txt; done
```

It means from regexp to end, delete..

Comment: thank you, this works really well. I am accepting tvm's answer because awk syntax is more readable for this case, but I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GNU sed, use `Q` instead of `q`:

`for i in foo/*/bazz.txt; do sed '/regexp/ Q' $i >> bazzdigest.txt; done`

This will output all lines before the match excluding the match itself.

Note that the `Q` command is a GNU extension.

Comment: The problem is that I don't need to output all lines of each file not matching the regexp, but lines up to the line matching the regexp. So, for example, if my file looks like:

a\nb\nc\nd\ne

And my regexp is /c/, my output needs to be:
a\nb\n
With my sed command, the output I get is:
a\nb\nc

Comment: I tried that, but sed says "invalid command code Q". Do I need a specific version of sed? I am using whatever is supplied with OS X 10.6.8

Comment: I used GNU sed 4.2.1 on Debian. The sed manpage states that the `Q` command is a GNU extension.